# How to get started with RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java

I have visited the following link:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Getting-Started

and have tried to get RxJava to work with Eclipse, however even after importing it using Maven it still won't find the Observer and Subscriber objects when trying to import them.

I am not too sure where to go from here as the getting started link doesn't explain it that thoroughly.

Comment: If you are not using Maven you can directly download the jar files and add them to your class path

Comment: Oh wow that was quite simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am also learning RxJava now, here is the necessary jar files you need:

If using Maven, add this dependency into pom:xml (replace with latest version available):

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.reactivex</groupId>
<artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
<version>1.0.11</version>
</dependency>
```

If you don't want to use Maven, I recommend you download the JAR file from Maven Repository:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.reactivex/rxjava

Regards, 
Cristi